# How to read lots of JSON-s from one file

Tags: java, android, json, file, gson

I don't have idea how to read file with lots of `JSON`-s in Android. I don't even know how many elements are in `JSON`. This is a part of `JSON`:

```
{
  "distance" : 0.0,
  "lat" : 52.297819,
  "lon" : 20.937653,
  "realTime" : 1553448972482,
  "speed" : "NaN",
  "time" : 0.0
}{
  "pulse" : 77,
  "rr" : [ 788 ],
  "time" : 1553448976957
}{
  "distance" : 0.0,
  "lat" : 52.297819,
  "lon" : 20.937653,
  "realTime" : 1553448977481,
  "speed" : "NaN",
  "time" : 0.0
}
```

I created two model `DTO` classes:

```
 public class GpsDTO{
    double lat;
    double lon;
    double speed;
    double distance;
    double time;
    long realTime;
}
 public class HeartDTO{
    long time;
    int pulse;
    int[] rr;
}
```

and I tried use library `GSON` but it does not work.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();
try {
    GpsDTO gpsDTO = gson.fromJson(new FileReader(path),GpsDTO.class);
} catch (Exception  e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON, is that your actual JSON file?

Comment: I write to .text and append to file json. All file is not json but contain lots of json

Comment: You won't be able to read an invalid JSON file as JSON.

Comment: Could not you split these `JSON` parts on many different files? Do you receive this from remote server as one big response? Do you have any control what do you write to this file? Maybe it will be much easier to change the way how these parts are stored than creating complex deserialisation solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presented `JSON` payload is not valid. `Gson` does not read invalid `JSON` payloads by default. We need to implement custom deserialiser for it. `JSON` structure in this case is list of `JSON object`-es. We can use `JsonReader` and stream `API`. The fastest way is to read it once but much easier it to read it twice:

- Read first time to find order of classes and adapters
- Read second time to deserialise `i - JSON objects` using given `i - adapter`

To match adapter below implementation uses all properties in `JSON` object (`findAdapters` method). In case it is not the best algorithm in your case, implement other which fits requirements:

```
class MultiJsonReader {

    // constant list of properties for each class
    private final List<String> HEART_PROPS = Arrays.asList("pulse", "rr", "time");
    private final List<String> GPS_PROPS = Arrays.asList("lat", "lon", "distance", "speed", "realTime", "time");

    private final Gson gson;

    public MultiJsonReader(Gson gson) {
        this.gson = gson;
    }

    public List<Object> readAll(File jsonFile) throws IOException {
        List<TypeAdapter<?>> adapters;
        // read first time for finding types and adapters
        try (JsonReader jsonReader = gson.newJsonReader(new FileReader(jsonFile))) {
            jsonReader.setLenient(true);
            adapters = findAdapters(gson, jsonReader);
        }

        List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();

        // read second time for deserialising
        try (JsonReader jsonReader = gson.newJsonReader(new FileReader(jsonFile))) {
            jsonReader.setLenient(true);
            for (TypeAdapter<?> adapter : adapters) {
                objects.add(adapter.read(jsonReader));
            }
        }

        return objects;
    }

    private List<TypeAdapter<?>> findAdapters(Gson gson, JsonReader jsonReader) throws IOException {
        List<TypeAdapter<?>> adapters = new ArrayList<>();

        while (jsonReader.peek() != JsonToken.END_DOCUMENT) {
            List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

            jsonReader.beginObject();
            while (jsonReader.peek() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
                names.add(jsonReader.nextName());
                jsonReader.skipValue();
            }
            jsonReader.endObject();

            Class<?> clazz = getClassForProperties(names);
            adapters.add(gson.getAdapter(clazz));
        }

        return adapters;
    }

    private Class<?> getClassForProperties(List<String> properties) {
        if (HEART_PROPS.containsAll(properties)) {
            return HeartDTO.class;
        }
        if (GPS_PROPS.containsAll(properties)) {
            return GpsDTO.class;
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Properties are not known " + properties);
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonToken;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class GsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        MultiJsonReader reader = new MultiJsonReader(gson);
        List<Object> objects = reader.readAll(jsonFile);

        objects.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

For your `JSON` payload prints:

```
GpsDTO{lat=52.297819, lon=20.937653, speed=NaN, distance=0.0, time=0.0, realTime=1553448972482}
HeartDTO{time=1553448976957, pulse=77, rr=[788]}
GpsDTO{lat=52.297819, lon=20.937653, speed=NaN, distance=0.0, time=0.0, realTime=1553448977481}
```